# lambdify no longer accepting dictionary of keyword args?

Tags: python, sympy

In SymPy version 0.7.5 I could define a lambdified function as follows...

```
Y, K, L = sym.var('Y, K, L')
params = {'A0': 1.0, 'g': 0.02, 'L0': 1.0, 'n': 0.02, 's': 0.15, 'alpha': 0.33, 'delta': 0.05}
args = [Y, K, L] + sym.var(list(params.keys()))
f = sym.lambdify(args, some_expression, my_modules)
```

and then call `f` as `f(10, 105, 10, **params)` to get the desired result. However after updating to SymPy 0.7.6 the above syntax raises an error.

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'g'
```

I can get the desired behavior by calling `f` as `f(10, 105, 10, *params.values())` but  would prefer the original behavior as I make use of this syntax regularly in my library code. I am wondering if this is a bug? Perhaps I have been "mis-using" lambdify all these years?

EDIT:
I went ahead and opened an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8536) on GitHub.

EDIT:
Full traceback is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f569fade366f> in <module>()
----> 1 model.compute_solow_residual(output, capital, labor).plot()

/Users/drpugh/Research/python-dev/quant-econ/quantecon/models/solow/model.py in     compute_solow_residual(self, Y, K, L)
    705 
    706     def compute_solow_residual(self, Y, K, L, ):
--> 707         return self._numeric_solow_residual(Y, K, L, **self.params)
    708 
    709     def find_steady_state(self, a, b, method='brentq', **kwargs):

TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'g'
```

Not sure that full traceback is useful as the problem seems to be within lambdify itself.

Comment: Will you please give full traceback ?

Comment: This has been answered on the issue page that is referred to above.